# Odoo 8.0 Qweb report: how to print sale.order.lines on one page?

Tags: odoo-8, qweb

I'm looking how to print the report on **selected** sale.order.lines, 
The conditions are:

- print all sale.order.lines in the table on one page (only if not fits continue on other pages),
- repeat table header only one time
- repeat company header only one time on the top of the document

Current behaviour is that all sale.order.lines are printed on the separate pages with header and footer repeated on every page;

Can any Odoo 8.0 specialist help me ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I Prefer Create a new module Report than Customize it using Qweb Report. It's more Easier

[Odoo Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/)

Answer (score 0):

1.create your custom report ,customize your report what ever you want.Give the paper format,and all the thing. 
[enter link description here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html)